# Disable caching in Fire Fox in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, caching

I have developed a web application that processes credit card payments and when a user hits the back button in Fire Fox after they received the payment confirmation page, it post a duplicate payment.

I have put the following code in both the payment form and confirmation page and it still posts duplicate payments:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

What I am doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Seams like the problem isn't the cacheing its that a duplicate payment is possible with a cached copy.

Comment: Michael, first I'd try this add-on to examine that your Cache settings are having the desired effect:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rerun has a good point in the comments. With regards to this problem, try this code ([source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1013531.aspx/1?How%20to%20prevent%20browser%20and%20proxy%20caching%20of%20web%20pages)):

```
   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private"); // HTTP 1.1
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
   Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "pre-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
   Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1 
   Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993"); // HTTP 1.1 
   Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // HTTP 1.1
```

It should force all browsers to get the latest version and not the cached version of a page. (Might want to change the `Expires` data has that post was from `2006`).

Answer (score 1):

For the more general issue of not performing duplicate processing, have a read of the suggestions given at [Not allow resubmit of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607913/not-allow-resubmit-of-page).

In summary, there are a few ways to try to stop the client's browser from repeating a request, but ultimately, if it's absolutely vital that submissions never get processed twice, you need to check on the server side whether a payment has already been processed. Add a unique identifier into the form that they submit, log it in the database, and if you see that same identifier a second time, *don't process the request*.