# Firefox not displaying panel on refresh or postback

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I have a curious issue. I have an ASP.NET web page that has a RadioButtonList with three RadioButtons. RadioButton1 hides both Panels. RadioButton2 displays Panel1 and hides Panel2 then RadioButton3 hides Panel1 and displays Panel2. Pretty straight forward. All of the logic that hide and display the Panels is in C# in the Code Behind. All of this works great in Chrome and IE. In Firefox; however, if you refresh the page in any way (another controls posts back or by hitting the browser's refresh button) while say RadioButton2 is selected and Panel1 is displayed the page comes back with the RadioButton2 still selected but both Panels are now hidden. In Chrome and IE a refresh of the page brings it back to it's original state. Meaning that all of the controls are set to their original values and RadioButton1 is selected and both Panels are hidden. Not necessarily ideal but a whole lot better than having the RadioButtons and Panels come back out of sync.

Not sure where to begin looking on this one. None of this is done in JavaScript. The panels and RadioButtons are not generated in code behind they are in the static HTML portion of the page.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really the answer I was hoping for because it seems incomprehensible to me that in 2014 we still have issues with browser inconsistencies but I put some code in the page to handle this and force it back into the proper state. This has solved the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you might be dealing with a page caching issue in Firefox. Have you tried disabling page caching for this page? For example, see this answer: [Disable caching in Fire Fox in ASP.NET and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273095/disable-caching-in-fire-fox-in-asp-net-and-c-sharp)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but this did not solve the problem. The RadioButtons still come back out of synch with the panels. I simply went back and forced it to reset properly in the code behind. I was able to do so without interfering with the normal operation of the page.